# How is a log inside bash or python script appended to a specific journald unit name?

Tags: systemd, logs, systemd-journald, journalctl

How do logs and prints inside scripts (bash, python etc) get associated to a unit name?

Suppose I have a very simple unit file test-service.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Test Unit

[Service]
Type=simple
User=myuser
Group=myuser
ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash /home/myuser/hello.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

and hello.sh contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello World"
```

when I try to show logs for that specific unit file I DON'T see the log line "Hello World":

```
journalctl -u test-service -f
-- Logs begin at Mon 2019-12-09 10:07:15 CET. -- Dec 09 10:10:51 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started Test Unit.
```

when I issue journalctl without filtering by unit I can see the log line:

```
journalctl -f
-- Logs begin at Mon 2019-12-09 10:07:15 CET. --
Dec 09 10:14:07 localhost.localdomain bash[4776]: Hello World
```

Now same thing happens for this unit file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Test Unit

[Service]
Type=simple
User=myuser
Group=myuser
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/myuser/test.py

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

and test.py contains:

```
import logging

class TestService(object):
    def __init__(self):
        logging.basicConfig()
        self.log = logging.getLogger("test-service")
        self.log.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    def hello_world(self):
        exit_code = 0
        print("Hello world, exit_code = {}".format(exit_code))
        self.log.info("Hello world!!!")
        exit(exit_code)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("starting up..")
    r = TestService()
    r.hello_world()
```

again when I try to show logs for that specific unit file I DON'T see the log line "Hello World":

```
journalctl -u test-service -f
-- Logs begin at Mon 2019-12-09 10:07:15 CET. --
Dec 09 10:10:51 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started Test Unit.
```

when I issue journalctl without filtering by unit I can see the log line:s

```
systemd[1]: Started Test Unit.
Dec 09 10:28:52 localhost.localdomain python[5449]: INFO:test-service:Hello world!!!
Dec 09 10:28:52 localhost.localdomain python[5449]: starting up..
Dec 09 10:28:52 localhost.localdomain python[5449]: Hello world, exit_code = 0
```

how is a script associated to a unit file in bash and python scripts?
Are "bash[4776]" and "python[5449]" the default unit names the scripts are associated to or what are the defaults?